# Mismatch in counts of Meta Sportsmanship badge

Tags: support, answers, voting, badges

The new profile page reveals how to get the badges ;-)

Well, at least in my case, there is a mismatch for the `Sportsmanship` badge. (See the screenshot or on my Meta Profile.)

As of now, it says, that I apparently upvoted 17 answers from other users on questions where I answered also. However, I 've got only 11 answers on Meta so far...

Does this count include multiple upvoting by me for other answers on a single question too? I always thought that only one upvote per question does count.

**Please note**: This is not a question on how to get this badge actually. I just noted this 'mismatch' by chance since the new profile system 'reports' *progresses*

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the [Sportsmanship badge definition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/168244):

> ### Sportsmanship
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Cast 100 upvotes on competing answers ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68156/168244))
>
>   - If you answer a question and earn a score of at least one, all other answers to that question are considered "competing answers"
>   - Deleted posts do not count
>   - Retracted votes do not count

Note that *all other answers* to a question where you have an answer score of at least one is considered "competing". While you have posted only [11 answers on Meta.TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A31729+is%3Aanswer):

[image]

some of these questions have multiple answers by other users as well. You must have upvoted multiple competing answers on some of these posts.

Without knowing your voting behaviour, it's impossible to say, but this would be my assumption.

Comment: I have voted especially on all contestants for the TUG membership question in January. I almost upvote any 'competing' answer